# Regex to parse comma delimited line where each element may contain comma or double quote

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find the regex expression I could to parse a line like:

> "hello","here, I am","Building "A" and more","Building "B", Indiana"

I expect to find

- "hello"
- "here, I am"
- "Building "A" and more"
- "Building "B", Indiana"

regex `(?:^|\,)(\"(?:[^\"]\,)*\"|[^\,]*)` will correctly parse elements with double quotes (such as `"Building "A" and more"`) and regex `(?:^|\,)(\"(?:[^\"]\,?)*\"|[^\,]*)` will parse elements with comma (such as `"here, I am"`) but I have a hard time finding 1 expression that will correctly parse both elements and also the last one which includes a comma and double quotes. Note that an element may contain more than 1 comma and double quote.

I will use this regex in a C# .NET Core 6 application.

Comment: I found this regex: "((?:.|\n)*?)"\s*[:!,}]\s*

It parses all except the last element and any other fields that would follow it.

Comment: Consider using a CSV parser. Someone has figured out all the edge cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this regex:

```
"'(?<v1>.+?)'(?=,')|'(?<v2>.+)'"g
```

Note: I've used single quotes just to be supported inside the Regex101.

Explanation:

1. `'(?<v1>.+?)'(?=,')` matches every quoted character following with a comma and a quote (first priority)
2. '(?.+)' if not followed by a comma, it should be a match too (second priority)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cruCOC/1)

Comment: That is very promising... I'm testing it now.

Comment: It works!!! With a small modif it parses empty fields:  '(.*?)'(?=\,')|'(.+)'